# Validation for amount of returned rows in API

Tags: c#, sql, api

I have an API which takes its model from the request. It transfers that to a small stored procedure. That SP selects some record by using some of the model's parameters. It returns the matching records as a list of objects. Finally the controller returns the response.

Simplified example:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromBody]TestModel testModel)
{
    var responseList = _testService.GetResponse(testModel);
    return Ok(responseList );
}
```

The API should not return more than 500 records at a time. If we have more than that the API should return with an error: "Your request would return more than 500 records".

What is the best solution to add validation for the number of retrieved records?

- Two selects with same conditions and joins, but one of them
  returns only the `count(*)`?
- Or return all data to the application and then count it there?
- Or something else?

Comment: Why not just implement paging?

Answer (score 2):

Normally when you are doing a REST API there are too many approaches to do this.

**Approach #1:**

One is at the SQL level, you need to pass to your sql logic pagination parameters like

```
public int PageNumber { get; set; } = 1;
private int PageSize = 500;
```

So you can select and skip the number of elements you want. What is the advantage on that? you can add some execution plans to your SQL queries, see what indexes are missing, you can optimize your query on the SQL side mostly. DBAs are normally in charge of these approaches in big organizations.

**Approach #2**

You can still write your query from your backend, at least this one is simple, and it will be executed on the SQL server side, below is an extension method you can use to do it.

```
    public static IQueryable<T> PageBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, int skipCount, int maxResultCount)
    {
       if (query == null)
       {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("query");
       }
       return query.Skip(skipCount).Take(maxResultCount);
    }
```

**Approach #3:**

Bring the data into memory(in this case will be executed on the server-side, not in the SQL server) and to the pagination from there. The only thing you need to do is to call a ToList() and that will materialize your query and bring it into memory where you can use the same idea of the **Approach #2**.

**Approach #4:**

This example will apply for .Net Core but sure there is a version of the package that can do the same thing for .NetFramework.
Use OData nugget package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData
```

Add `EnableQueryAttribute` and pass `ODataQueryOptions<TestModel> options`, Odata use some extension methods over `IQueryble`

```
[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<TestModel> options)
{
    //this should return an IQueryble<T>
    var responseList = _testService.GetResponse(testModel);  
    var ret= options.ApplyToWithDefaultTop(responseList, ignoreQueryOptions);
    return Ok(ret);
}
```

here is my extension method to apply a default count of elements to bring

```
public static IQueryable ApplyToWithDefaultTop<T>(this ODataQueryOptions<T> options, 
            IQueryable<T> query, AllowedQueryOptions ignoreQueryOptions)
        {
            if (options.Top == null)
            {
                //this is the default
                query = query.Take(500);
            }

            //odata extension method
            return options.ApplyTo(query, ignoreQueryOptions);
        }
```

This will do the same thing as **Approach #2**, but you don't need to worry about the parameters model, they are part of the Odata syntax, for example, here I am returning 40 elements of that resource and skipping the first 2 pages.

```
https://localhost:44335/api/weather_forecast?$top=40&$skip=2
```

Only adding 4 lines of code you are good to put on top of your API the Odata syntax, on your Configure method

```
   app.UseMvc(routerBuilder =>
    {
        routerBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
        //adding MaxTop from appsettings with a value of 100
        //routerBuilder.Select().OrderBy().Filter().Count().MaxTop(Configuration.GetValue<int>("Odata:MaxTop"));
        routerBuilder.Expand().Select().Count().OrderBy().Filter().MaxTop(Configuration.GetValue<int>("500"));
    });
```

and in `ConfigureServices` add `services.AddOData();`

For more references see this article: [OData article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/experimenting-with-odata-in-asp-net-core-3-1/)

**Recommendation**

If your API has more than 500 you should not throw an error to the client, just give him the first 500
Also, you can pass the PageSize and validate that number without going to your database and return the error in case you still want to go with this approach. Don't let the application fail when you can validate the input. You can use as well FluentValidation nugget package in order to validate your `DTOs`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an `Output` to the SP. and set it if `count` is greater than 500 and select records else don't do anything in SP. in C# code just first check the output value first and then process accordingly.

Comment: So, it will be two selects in SP?

Comment: yes if the count is less than 500, otherwise no. you can do in one select. but it will get the records along with the count like (`select (count(*), col1, col2.....`

Answer (score 0):

As @viveknuna pointed out you can use an out parameter to indicate the retrieved row count.

I would add some small additions to his suggestion:

1) It was suggested to set that parameter only if the predefined threshold is exceeded. I would suggest to set it every time and check it inside your application code. It gives you much more flexibility.

2) You should not need to use two selects. `@@ROWCOUNT` or `ROWCOUNT_BIG()` I would suggest to read [this excellent article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6091/how-to-use-rowcount-in-sql-server/) about this topic.